# iPhone Natural Language processing for dates

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have dates in the format 'May 28, 2011' or 'February 23, 2011'.  I want to know what the best way to turn these into NSDate's would be.  I am thinking of just writing my own formatter but am curious if there is a built in class to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to subclass it. Just set a generic formatter's date style to NSDateFormatterLongStyle and get your date from its -dateFromString: method.

Comment: That's great, that's what I did.  Thank you.